# How to create a array of hash in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays

I want to create an array of hash like this

```
array[0] = {'a' => 10, 'b' => 20, 'c' => 30 }
array[1] = {'a' => 10, 'b' => 20, 'c' => 30 }
....
```

And I want to create the array by adding each element one by one like this

```
array[1] add {'a' => 10}
array[1] add {'b' => 20}
array[1] add {'c' => 30}

array[2] add {'a' => 10}
array[2] add {'b' => 20}
array[2] add {'c' => 30}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: You mean all the array elements will be same hash object or different ?

Comment: http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:yPC4G6n0YNQJ:stackoverflow.com/questions/23693141/create-an-array-of-hashes-in-rails+&cd=2&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
array = []

3.times do |i|
  array[i] = {'a' => 10}
  array[i].merge!({'b' => 20})
  array[i].merge!({'c' => 30})
end
```

This would populate the array from `array[0]` to `array[2]`.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `merge!`:

```
array[1] = {}
array[1].merge!('a' => 10)
array[1].merge!('b' => 20)
array[1].merge!('c' => 30)
```

Comment: Or try using << instead of merge.  
array[1] << {'a' => 10}

Comment: @SrikanthJeeva That wouldn't work..

Comment: @uri - why not `#merge!` or `update` ?

Comment: @Arup Right it wont work! Sorry I thought [{"a"=>10},{"b"=>20}]

Comment: @ArupRakshit of course `merge!` is the right API...